# Failed: invalid element state on attempt to .sendKeys() to a text field

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I keep getting `Failed: invalid element state` error on attempt to `sendKeys()` to a text box to which I'm able to if I'm in `browser.explore()` mode.

the Text field is validating entry against active userIDs. Please note that I'm able to use the same command `sendKeys()` when I'm in `browser.explore()` mode

**UPDATE: I'm not able to post HTML code as there is a char. limit and I have over 7500 arrays [object Object]**
here is a screenshot, if it helps 
[screenshot of the field and its HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2vU7.png)

**my code:**

```
var businessOwner = element(by.name("productManager"));
businessOwner.sendKeys('someValue');
```

> error:- Failed: invalid element state
>          (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
>          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522932 (4140ab217e1ca1bec0c4b4d1b148f3361eb3a03e),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
>          (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
>          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522932 (4140ab217e1ca1bec0c4b4d1b148f3361eb3a03e),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
>            at WebDriverError (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
>            at InvalidElementStateError (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:100:5)
>            at Object.checkLegacyResponse (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
>            at parseHttpResponse (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
>            at doSend.then.response (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
>            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
>        From: Task: WebElement.sendKeys()
>            at Driver.schedule (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
>            at WebElement.schedule_ (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1921:25)
>            at WebElement.sendKeys (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2084:19)
>            at actionFn (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:94:34)
>            at Array.map (native)
>            at actionResults.getWebElements.then (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:484:67)
>            at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
>            at TaskQueue.execute_ (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
>            at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
>            at asyncRun (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
>            at ...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
>            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)Error
>            at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:482:23)
>            at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:96:21)
>            at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:873:14)
>            at ...pathToMyApp/e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts:204:17
>            at elementArrayFinder_.then (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:840:22)
>            at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
>            at TaskQueue.execute_ (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
>            at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
>            at asyncRun (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
>            at ...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
>            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
>        From: Task: Run it("I fill teamsAndOwners Form") in control flow
>            at UserContext. (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
>            at ...pathToMyApp/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:64:48
>            at ControlFlow.emit (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/events.js:62:21)
>            at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2565:10)
>            at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2490:53)
>            at MicroTask.asyncRun (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2619:9)
>            at ...pathToMyApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
>            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
>        From asynchronous test:
>        Error
>            at Suite. (...pathToMyApp/e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts:170:1)
>            at Object. (...pathToMyApp/e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts:7:1)
>            at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>            at Module.m._compile (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:382:23)
>            at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>            at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (...pathToMyApp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:385:12)
>            at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>            at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>            at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>            at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>            at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

**I've tried:**

1.

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(businessOwner.get(0)), 30000, 'businessOwner is not there ');
businessOwner.sendKeys(UID);
```

same error no matter what the timeout is

2.

```
function setBusinessOwner(UID: string){
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(businessOwner), 20000).then(function(){
        businessOwner.click().then(function(){
            businessOwner.sendKeys(UID);
});
});
}
setBusinessOwner('someValue');
```

same error.

***UPDATE(9am): 
seem like its timing issue (most likely)

adding browser.sleep(10000) allows my script to sendKeys without error.

why browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(businessOwner) does not work then ... ? 
*** UPDATE(1020am)
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(businessOwner)  seem to be working. testing and if works, will resolve this issue

Comment: please let me know what information is needed to troubleshoot this. 
thank you in advance

Comment: i only know sendKeys as method of a WebDriver and not of a HTMLElement. How it works with the WebDriver you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632923/using-javascriptexecutor-to-sendkeys-plus-click-on-web-element

Comment: at which location you are getting this error. It will help me to investigate if you share complete log.

Comment: @mtizziani, 
sorry if I'm not clear: I'm not able to post the HTML of the element to show how it looks

Comment: @YashJagdale, i've updated the issue with a log

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that finally works

```
function setBusinessOwner(UID: string){
  browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(businessOwner), 20000).then(function(){
      businessOwner.sendKeys(UID);
});
}
setBusinessOwner('abc1234');
```

elementToBeClickable - seem to be working. I don't know what is the implementation difference between elementToBeClickable and visibilityOf, but visibilityOf was not working out for me

Comment: visibilityOf is wait till element is visible, It will return true once element available in dom. 
elementToBeClickable - Wait untill that element is not clickable.(it will return false if any button is visible but not clickable.) - Hope this help you